# How to add application to startup application menu?

Tags: 12.04, startup

I tried add some applications to add startup menu. But they didn't started with computer. Please Anybody help me to do that. I used only GUI method to add apllications to menu in ubuntu 12.04.Somebody please help me to do that correctly. Forget about my bad English.

Comment: What applications do you want to start?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First you need to know the command of the application you want to start or the location of its binary.  The command of the application is usually its name.  For example, if you type `firefox` into a terminal it will start Firefox.

To make Firefox start on startup, open "Startup Applications" from the dash.  Click 'Add' then fill out the 'Command' field with the command for the application, in this case `firefox`. Or, if you know the location of the executable file, click "Browse..." and navigate to the file.  The 'Name' and 'Comment' fields are optional.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. You explained it clearly. thank you again

Comment: How do you do this in 14.10? Because, the newer version no longer has "startup applications" and the Add button in Tweak Tool is broke.

Comment: @DarthCoder I have startup applications in my install of 14.10. Did you do a fresh install or an upgrade?

Comment: What happens when you run `gnome-session-properties`?

Comment: @Seth I installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and upgraded to 14.10 and don't have startup applications on the current version. Also, when I try to run thr gnome-session-properties, it tells me to install gnome-session-bin, which is already currently installed and at the newest level.

Comment: @DarthCoder That probably has something to do with it. I don't run Ubuntu gnome so I can't help much. You could ask a new question though.