# How to connect to WiFi from the command line?

Tags: wireless, command-line, network-manager, panel

Other posts seems to be addressing more complicated network connection issues from the command line.

The Unity panel Network indicator/button doesn't respond too well sometimes - it keeps trying to connect to a network even when i click on "disconnect", stuff like that.

So I want to go command line for the control.  I don't like GUIs anyway.

Is there not some simple command line tool which can do something like the following?

```
wifi connect MyNetworkNameA
wifi disconnect
wifi connect MyNetworkNameB
```

Comment: Depends , what wireless security ? This is covered in detail here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic#Wireless

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 and on 18.04, still experiencing wifi disconnects. A reconnect command would be a good hack.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

I think you want to keep using managed interface (by NetworkManager). `nmcli` is a command‐line tool for controlling NetworkManager.

- To see list of saved connections, use (`<SavedWiFiConn>`)

  ```
  nmcli c
  ```
- To see list of available WiFi hotspots (`<WiFiSSID>`)

  ```
  nmcli d wifi list
  ```

  or:

  ```
  sudo iwlist <WifiInterface> scanning
  ```
- To see list of interfaces (`<WifiInterface>`)

  ```
  ifconfig -a
  ```

Just change `<WifiInterface>`, `<WiFiSSID>`, `<WiFiPassword>` in the following commands to reflect your setup. If WiFi info already saved, easier way using `<SavedWiFiConn>` name of connection as it was saved in NetworkManager.

### Ubuntu 16.04

```
##disconnect
nmcli d disconnect <WifiInterface>

##connect
nmcli d connect <WifiInterface>
```

Another way:

```
##disconnect
nmcli c down <SavedWiFiConn>

##connect
nmcli c up <SavedWiFiConn>
```

### Ubuntu 15.10 & previous

```
##disconnect
nmcli d disconnect iface <WifiInterface>

##connect
nmcli d wifi connect <WiFiSSID> password <WiFiPassword> iface <WifiInterface>
```

Another way:

```
##disconnect:
nmcli c down id <SavedWiFiConn>

##connect:
nmcli c up id <SavedWiFiConn>
```

If your password isn't automatically recognized type this:

```
nmcli -a c up <SavedWiFiConn>
```

**Reference:** [`man nmcli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nmcli.1.html)

Comment: Works like a charm!  And, as suspected, the command line responds immediately, while the GUI can be sluggish, uncooperative, and unresponsive sometimes.

Comment: Saved my day when I lost my Unity dash and taskbar, and the Network Settings dialog kept on crashing upon any kind of network connection establishment.

Comment: is there a way to  automate it so it connects whenever the wifi is available ?

Comment: @kirill_igum , sorry to be late quiet busy, You may use `cron` for  scheduling wifi scan using `iwlist wlan0 scanning` or `nmcli d wifi list` then `nmcli ` to connect to the corresponding wifi network depending on your needs.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 this connect command returns `Error: Device 'wlan0' is not an Wi-Fi device.` I believe this answer is incomplete.

Comment: This is invalid syntax. `Unknown parameter: iface` `Unknown parameter: wlan0`

Comment: I have no idea how this works for me.  I am using blue tooth tether.  bnep0 but I do not know what to type or how to get the ssid.  I googled it and almost all of the commands did not do anything or were invalid or returned an empty line.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti, Try using `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning` or `nmcli d wifi list` to get the available networks ssid's.

Comment: "iwlist wlan0" says invalid command but iwlist alone is a command that works but just give a list of params to use.  nmcli d wifi list gives and empty header.  I am using blue tooth tether.

Comment: Can someone give me an example of what follows the parameter "ID", as in the command `nmcli c up id <WiFiConn>`.  What is a "`<WiFiConn>`"?

Comment: @L.D.James, the name used to save the connection settings, 1st column in this output `nmcli c` which list all saved connection setups

Comment: @sneetsher Ok.  I see.  I believe you have to replace the word `id` with the information in first column, otherwise you get an error.  It wasn't initially clear in the answer.

Comment: @L.D.James, It is already mentioned: `<WiFiConn>` name of connection as it was save in NetworkManager (Check `nmcli c`). Or it  is not clear enough.

Comment: The command that I was issuing was giving an error.  I was issuing this command: `nmcli c up id "Apollo III Connect"`  It gave an error.  When I leave out the word `id` and typed this it connects without error: `nmcli c "Apollo III Connect"`.   I understand how to connect it now.  You're saying `id` as the parameter and saying replace the word `id` with the name of the connection, which you are naming <WiFiConn>.  Thanks!

Comment: @L.D.James, Are you using 16.04 release ? Could you tell your output of `nmcli -v`?

Comment: `mcli tool, version 1.2.0`

Comment: How to save a connection setup? If it's the first time I connect to a wifi!

Comment: To save a connection setup:
`sudo nmcli dev wifi con "SSID_NAME" password PASSWORD "CONFIG_NAME"`
To find auto your saved connection setups:
`nmcli c`

Comment: @Cirelli94 Good you seem already found it, just connecting to new wifi makes nm save it on new entry, no extra.

Comment: `nmcli` doesnt seem to be installed by default on server installs. How do we install it (particularly if we have no working network connection)? Alternatively, how do we perform these steps with `iw`, which is installed by default, but seems a lot harder to use?

Comment: when password is wrong, nmcli pops up a GUI input box (for retyping the correct password). this can't be scripted - is there a way to disable GUI ?

Comment: @BerryTsakala you may check beforehand if the SSID has the `Security` field with a value different than `none`.

Answer (score 147):

**`nmtui` ncurses solution**

Great interactive ncurses network manager option:

```
nmtui
```

If for some reason it is not installed, the Debian package is:

```
sudo apt install network-manager
```

Comes in the same package as `nm-applet` (the default top bar icon thing) and `nm-cli`, and is therefore widely available.

Screenshot:

[image]

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, my Ubuntu refused to connect to Wifi, so I plugged in the Ethernet cable and clicked Activate on Wired Connection and BAM!

Comment: @Downvoters please explain, I never retaliate ;-)

Comment: works on Ubuntu 16.01 as well, cool solution!

Comment: This is a much more intuitive solution than what is above IMO.  Unless you're trying to learn how Linux/Unix connects to WiFi, this seems like the ideal select and press enter solution.  Works well on Ubuntu 18

Comment: This "just worked " on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: and Jetson Nano ... and usefully it kept eth0 up too (I'm running headless and didn't lose the ssh session)

Comment: F***ING THANK YOU! Over the years I've had to rescue a laptop several times, and I always have to look up the spells required for wifi. `nmtui` is the best solution and just works!

Answer (score 27):

If your wi-fi access point is saved, it will auto-connect. Turn wireless on or off with a simpler command:

```
nmcli nm wifi on
nmcli nm wifi off
```

on newer version:

```
nmcli radio wifi on
nmcli radio wifi off
```

For reference, see [`man nmcli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/nmcli.1).

Comment: How do you make NM enable wifi automatically during boot? Every time I reboot, Network Manager starts with wifi disabled.

Comment: @Cerin, you may try adding this command to startup applications, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/243139/how-to-add-application-to-startup-application-menu

Comment: And how do in Ubuntu > 14.04.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to connect to a network called `PrettyFlyForAWiFi-5G`

```
nmcli -a d wifi connect PrettyFlyForAWiFi-5G
```

`-a` (or `--ask`) means it will ask you for the password. The connection will be saved and should connect automatically if you restart your computer.

You could append `password <your password>` to the end (the literal word `password` followed by the actual password)

```
nmcli d wifi connect PrettyFlyForAWiFi-5G password 12345678
```

but maybe run `unset HISTFILE` beforehand, so that your WiFi password isn't saved to your `~/.bash_history` file.

---

To see all the WiFi networks around you (`--rescan yes` is optional, the list of networks might be up to 30 seconds old without it)

```
nmcli d wifi list --rescan yes
```

which will output something like

```
IN-USE  SSID                         MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
        PrettyFlyForAWiFi-5G         Infra  44    405 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
        PrettyFlyForAWiFi            Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  41      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
```

To forget a connection (that was saved after you ran `nmcli -a d wifi connect <name>`)

```
nmcli c delete PrettyFlyForAWiFi-5G
```

To see a list of all saved connections

```
nmcli c
```

---

You can use `nmcli connection` instead of `nmcli c <whatever>` and `nmcli device` instead of `nmcli d`

[`nmcli`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager#Graphical_front-ends_and_command_line_interfaces) is the command line interface for [NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager) (which is part of [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME), Ubuntu's default desktop environment) and is already installed on Ubuntu.

Don't forget to set up your country code for using the perfect regulations:

```
sudo iw reg set <2 letter country code>

sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Comment: When using nmcli, there is a pop up to reask the password if it was miss-typed. Would you know whether there is a possibility of disabling this feature? Quite annoying when trying to use nmcli in a non-interactive script...