# ubuntu 14.04 connect to a wifi network using command line

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 server and I need to connect to my WiFi network. How can I connect to my WiFi network using only the command line.

Comment: You could also use this answer too, if you have NetworkManager installed (this is the way I do it on Ubuntu Server): http://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line

Answer (score 10):

First run iwconfig to see if the wireless extensions are enabled.

```
sudo su
iwconfig
```

If you are informed that there is a card, for example wlan0 and wireless interface is recognized as you are going to:

Second to view the available wireless networks run iwlist

```
sudo su
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Networks will show at your fingertips. Note the proper ESSID, which then need to enter.

Third, knowing the ESSID and the network password, run:

```
sudo su
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid <ESSID>
iwconfig wlan0 key s:<password_wireless>
```

In the last command, the s: is to indicate that what is below is a sequence of characters.

If the key is in hexadecimal numbers put the key starting with 0x:

Fourth, you must request an IP address from the DHCP server, or by ifconfig if you give the IP, netmask, gateway, etc.:

```
sudo su
dhclient wlan0
```

The steps can be automated script:

```
sudo su
nano /etc/init.d/wifi-on.sh
```

A simple text file with the following content:

```
!/bin/bash
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid <ESSID>
iwconfig wlan0 key s:<password_wireless>
dhclient wlan0
```

Control + O. save file. Control + X, close nano.

And you give execute permissions and add the system startup:

```
sudo su
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/wifi-on.sh
update-rc.d wifi-on.sh defaults
```

Comment: what if the network requires a username?

Comment: This answer only works for WEP networks.