# Terminal says "Interface doesn't support scanning"

Tags: networking, wireless

I have been trying to get Wi-Fi to work on Ubuntu 14.04 (I just don't and can't get ethernet) I have been trying too follow the guidline here: [ubuntu 14.04 connect to a wifi network using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522842/ubuntu-14-04-connect-to-a-wifi-network-using-command-line) but it wouldn't scan because it said "Interface doesn't support scanning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off using `nmcli` instead of the method described in the answer you followed. 
To list available wifi access points (aka routers ) in range:

`nmcli dev wifi`

To connect to a network for the first time, follow the example in the `man nmcli`:

`nmcli dev wifi con "Cafe Hotspot 1" password caffeine name "My cafe"`

To check if you are connected , use `nmcli device status` or `nmcli dev list` (14.04)  , or `nmcli dev show` for 15.04

If you already have a connection established, `nmcli con list` for 14.04 or `nmcli con show` for 15.04.

If you want to connect to one of those connections listed by `nmcli con lsit`, do `nmcli con up id "My Network Name"`

Comment: I got as far as the nmcli dev wifi con "Cafe Hotspot 1"  password caffeine name "My cafe".it just says "Error: No WiFi device found" I know the WiFi is within a desirable range cause on the Mac OSX side the internet runs perfectly...

Comment: Interesting. And is your wifi card detected properly ? does a line with `wlan0` or any wlan show up when you run `iwconfig` ? What does it say ? What does `sudo lshw -c network` say ?

Comment: When I tried iwconfig I got:                         eth0        no wireless extensions.               lo            no  wireless extensions. And if I do sudo Ishw -c network I get command not found.

Comment: Very interesting.  Are you sure you typed `sudo lshw -c network` correctly ? this program is supposed to show what kind of hardware you have, so to at least start troubleshooting, we need to know which wireless card you have.

Comment: I have a sim card in a huawei mobile wifi dongle.

Comment: I have a sim card in a huawei mobile wifi dongle,                                             I am as of yet positive I typed the code right, though could I have typed it wrong?  I don't really know what I'm doing so...

Comment: @Turon well, hard to say. I've never dealt with dongles that have sim card before,  only regular usb wifi dongle. I use  rtl8192, it's quite reliable, so if you don't figure out with this card, just get same as mine .  Personally, I think it's driver problem, but at least we would need to know what model of card it is. How about `lsusb`

Comment: Open a terminal window (CTRL + t) and enter `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lshw -c net; rfkill list all`  You can copy the command by highlighting with mouse/touchpad and copy, then click in the terminal window, then right click and select paste, then highlight the terminal results and right click and select copy.  Edit your question to include this information

Comment: okay Serg I put lsusb into the terminal and this is what I  got: http://www.mediafire.com/download/0kv5566ahr040s0/my_results_from_lsusb Jeremy31 I put your code in and I got this:http://www.mediafire.com/download/v8lf44mtnmr6ei9/results_from_lspci_etc

Comment: okay I've done all I can! what must I do?

Comment: What must I do from here?