# How to connect to a network without having a GUI at any point of time?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I have gone through other questions on connecting to a Wi-Fi network from a terminal. nmcli works from the command line if the password provided is correct. If the password is wrong:

1. The network manager opens a dialog box asking for the right password
2. The command doesn't exit till I click on "Cancel" (returns 4 on cancel)

Is there a way to try to connect to a network without having this dialog box pop up if there is an error?

I need this to connect to a Wi-Fi network from a `ctrl` + `alt` + `F<num>` terminal. Here it just keeps waiting and the prompt doesn't return.

Comment: sounds like a bug, I suggest you file a bug report. You have several alternates, all outlined here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

Comment: Network manager in full tty environment does print an error on console. You seem to have been trying this only in GUI with terminal emulator. Open tty2 with ctrl+alt+f2 , and try there

Comment: @Serg - I tried it in tty2; it's the same result. I am not getting the prompt back and when I shift to unity (ctrl + alt + f7) the network manager's dialog box is open.

Comment: I am using timeout to exit. It still opens a dialog box but my program gets to know that something is wrong. Syntax `timeout 30 nmcli ...`. 30 indicates that the command will return after 30 seconds in case of an error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see your Ubuntu release ID and I do not know why you want to avoid the NetworkManager GUI but here is an alternative to using NetworkManager:

1. Put the connection name and attributes in /etc/network/interfaces.  This will cause NetworkManager to ignore this interface as "unmanaged".
2. See the Answer in [ubuntu 14.04 connect to a wifi network using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522842/ubuntu-14-04-connect-to-a-wifi-network-using-command-line)