# while upgrading from ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 the computer crashed and I had to reboot

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, crash, 14.10

while upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 the computer crashed and I had to reboot when I entered Ubuntu I couldn't do a thing: the GUI wasn't working  correctly actually when I enter my user name and password I enter to a blue screen.

what can I do to return my system ?

if there wasn't any solution except reintalling the system from a USB or a DVD so how can I make a backup from my apps in the old system?

Comment: Since you mentioned "blue screen" I assume you are running a dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: yes I dual boot with windows

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If the answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue too. To resolve I did the following.

- Boot up ubuntu until you have the "blue screen"
- Go into a text console using the key combo `< Ctrl>< Alt>F1`. You should see a user/password prompt
- Log into the text console with your user account
- Ensure package list is updated: `sudo apt-get update`
- I got a message at the end saying configuration of packages was interrupted earlier, instructing me to do the following:`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- Now to complete, ensure package installation complete (this step might be superfluous): `sudo apt-get install -f`
- Now remove packages which are no longer required: `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- Now reboot: `sudo reboot`

Result: blue screen gone and can log in again.

Comment: I also needed an `apt-get upgrade` ([with internet](http://askubuntu.com/a/461831/349837) of course).