# How to connect to Protected EAP (PEAP) wifi via terminal

Tags: command-line, networking, gnome

My friend needs to connect to the wifi in our school, which uses a Protected EAP (PEAP) Authentification.

He installed the Gnome GUI by the way.

When he tries to connect to the wifi however, after putting the login and password, a window pops up warning that he didn't select a CA certificate (which is not needed), and he can't interact with that window. Meaning that he can't select ignore and then connect.

Is there a way to connect to this network by using the terminal?

Edit: My question was identified as similar to another, but the answers there doesn't help us. The network we are trying to connect to is one that needs username and password [Protected EAP (PEAP)]. The question/answers from the other thread only talk about the usual wifi where we only need to input the wifi's password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connect to wifi from command line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the words of [kemtnbkr on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2059808&p=12249108#post12249108):

> Make sure `wpasupplicant` is installed
>
> 1. Remove network manager from startup apps; log out and log back in
> 2. change your `/etc/network/interfaces` to: Code:
>
>    ```
>    auto lo
>    iface lo inet loopback
>
>    auto wlan0
>    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
>    wireless-mode Managed
>    wpa-ssid **censored**
>    wpa-ap-scan 1
>    wpa-proto RSN WPA
>    wpa-pairwise CCMP TKIP
>    wpa-group CCMP TKIP
>    wpa-key-mgmt WPA-EAP
>    wpa-eap PEAP
>    wpa-identity **censored**
>    wpa-password **censored**
>    wpa-phase1 fast_provisioning=1
>    wpa-pac-file /home/kyle/Downloads/chain2.cer
>    ```
> 3. With terminal: Code:
>
>    ```
>    sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
>    sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
>    sudo dhclient wlan0 -v
>    ```
> 4. You are Connected.