# Installed Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi

Tags: 14.04, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi. When I insert the SD card into the Raspberry Pi, it is taking me to a command window. How do I switch to desktop view or GUI?

I am not able to connect to the Internet to install all libraries.

Comment: Looks like [the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) has you covered.

Comment: @mikewhatever Yes I have followed wiki, but the problem is while installing xubuntu or any other installation it is throwing error to download. I have to connect to internet before installing. Could you please advice, how to connect to internet before the setup/installations?

Comment: @pradeep: That would be a separate issue. Please search for an existing question or open a new question, that covers it.

Comment: You may also want to check out [RaspberryPi.SE](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You might need to run the following command to install a desktop environment:

```
tasksel
```

or

```
sudo tasksel
```

.

However, you will need to connect to the internet.

To connect to the internet, run the following commands.

First, edit the following file using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Make sure the contents look like this and of course you will need to replace **ssid_name** with the name of the network and **password** with the actual password!:

```
network={
            ssid="ssid_name"
             psk="password"
}
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Then, run the following command:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext && sudo dhclient wlan0
```

Finally, check your network connection by running the following command:

```
iwconfig
```

Your ESSID should be listed.

Alternatively, you may be able to connect like this instead:

```
nmcli d wifi connect <WiFiSSID> password <WiFiPassword> iface wlan0
```

Again, replace `<WifiSSID>` with the actual name of the network and replace `<WiFiPassword>` with the actual password.

[Additional info 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line)

[Additional info 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line/461831#461831)

---

**NOTE:** [because of a bug in tasksel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1779645), DO NOT use tasksel to uninstall packages. ONLY use tasksel to install.

Comment: @mchid- could you please advice how to connect to internet to install the packages..

Comment: I am using sandisk SD card of 8 gigabytes.

Comment: how do you know you have no internet? is your ethernet cable plugged in?

Comment: i am using wifi dongle .. If it is connected it, LED light will glow on the dongle. More over my wifi network is password protected.

Comment: @pradeep I have updated the answer

Comment: @pradeep http://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line