# Changing wireless networks causes system crash

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

On my computer with an "ASUS X99-PRO"-motherboard I have a semi-random system hang about 25% of the time when I change the wireless network. The adapter is:

```
> lspci | grep -i wireless
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

The system doesn't provide any feedback that I can see, both mouse and keyboard become non-responsive and the only way is to do a hardware reboot. At first I thought this was something related to the UI since it became non-responsive and I used the [terminal alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line):

```
nmcli c up id <WiFiConn>
```

Unfortunately the problem remains and since my wireless is unstable this is starting to annoy me. I'm rather clueless on where to start, any advice?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with everything updated. Below is my sys-log prior to the system crash:

```
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/6c:71:d9:f2:d1:a7
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/6c:71:d9:f2:d1:a7
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 1##.###.###.### on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6f19a123)
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer dhclient: DHCPACK of 1##.###.###.### from 1.1.1.1
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer dhclient: bound to 1##.###.###.### -- renewal in 861 seconds.
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info>   address 1##.###.###.###
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info>   prefix 21 (255.255.248.0)
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info>   gateway 1a#.###.###.###
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info>   nameserver '1b#.###.###.###'
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info>   nameserver '1c#.###.###.###'
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info>   domain name 'net.provider.se'
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer avahi-daemon[658]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 1##.###.###.###.
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer avahi-daemon[658]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 14 12:32:41 mycomputer avahi-daemon[658]: Registering new address record for 1##.###.###.### on wlan0.IPv4.
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> Policy set 'DS Guest' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer dnsmasq[2649]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer dnsmasq[2649]: using nameserver 1c#.###.###.####53
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer dnsmasq[2649]: using nameserver 1b#.###.###.####53
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer avahi-daemon[658]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address ####::####:####:####:####.
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer avahi-daemon[658]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer avahi-daemon[658]: Registering new address record for ####::####:####:####:#### on wlan0.*.
Dec 14 12:32:42 mycomputer whoopsie[1365]: message repeated 5 times: [ offline]
Dec 14 12:32:45 mycomputer whoopsie[1365]: Could not get the list of active connections: Timeout was reached
Dec 14 12:32:45 mycomputer whoopsie[1365]: offline
Dec 14 12:32:50 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> (wlan0): roamed from BSSID ##:##:##:##:##:## (DS Guest) to DC:EB:94:97:78:F1 (DS Guest)
Dec 14 12:32:50 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
Dec 14 12:32:50 mycomputer dbus[609]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Dec 14 12:32:50 mycomputer dbus[609]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 14 12:32:55 mycomputer sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/max is already mounted
Dec 14 12:32:57 mycomputer ntpdate[6385]: adjust time server 1d#.###.###.### offset -0.062355 sec
Dec 14 12:32:57 mycomputer wpa_supplicant[2637]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 14 12:33:01 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Dec 14 12:33:01 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Dec 14 12:33:01 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Dec 14 12:33:01 mycomputer NetworkManager[1042]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Dec 14 12:33:17 mycomputer dbus[609]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.apt' (using servicehelper)
Dec 14 12:33:17 mycomputer AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Dec 14 12:33:17 mycomputer dbus[609]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.apt'
Dec 14 12:33:17 mycomputer AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
```

The dmesg output (the wireless part that seems related):

```
[ 1180.647123] WARNING: CPU: 10 PID: 5043 at /build/linux-lts-vivid-3x86XO/linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0/net/wireless/sme.c:664 __cfg80211_connect_result+0x3bb/0x400 [cfg80211]()
[ 1180.647125] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi dm_crypt eeepc_wmi nvidia(POE) asus_wmi sparse_keymap video mxm_wmi wl(POE) intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic btusb kvm dm_multipath scsi_dh crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_intel ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_controller aesni_intel snd_hda_codec aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hwdep snd_seq_midi gf128mul glue_helper snd_seq_midi_event ablk_helper cryptd snd_rawmidi serio_raw cfg80211 snd_pcm snd_seq lpc_ich snd_seq_device snd_timer sb_edac edac_core snd drm soundcore mei_me mei shpchp 8250_fintek wmi tpm_infineon bnep rfcomm bluetooth binfmt_misc mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq raid1 raid0 multipath linear dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage psmouse e1000e ahci libahci ptp pps_core
[ 1180.647200] CPU: 10 PID: 5043 Comm: kworker/u24:2 Tainted: P        W  OE  3.19.0-28-generic #30~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[ 1180.647203] Hardware name: Exertis_CapTech All Series/X99-PRO, BIOS 1901 08/10/2015
[ 1180.647214] Workqueue: cfg80211 cfg80211_event_work [cfg80211]
[ 1180.647216]  ffffffffc076f4f8 ffff880f7c447c68 ffffffff817aed97 0000000000000000
[ 1180.647220]  0000000000000000 ffff880f7c447ca8 ffffffff81074d8a ffff8810371c6478
[ 1180.647223]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffff881033809818 ffff8810371c6400
[ 1180.647227] Call Trace:
[ 1180.647239]  [<ffffffff817aed97>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
[ 1180.647245]  [<ffffffff81074d8a>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8a/0xc0
[ 1180.647248]  [<ffffffff81074e7a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[ 1180.647264]  [<ffffffffc074cadb>] __cfg80211_connect_result+0x3bb/0x400 [cfg80211]
[ 1180.647278]  [<ffffffffc0728073>] cfg80211_process_wdev_events+0x153/0x1d0 [cfg80211]
[ 1180.647291]  [<ffffffffc0728128>] cfg80211_process_rdev_events+0x38/0x70 [cfg80211]
[ 1180.647301]  [<ffffffffc0723022>] cfg80211_event_work+0x22/0x30 [cfg80211]
[ 1180.647306]  [<ffffffff8108db6f>] process_one_work+0x14f/0x400
[ 1180.647309]  [<ffffffff8108e308>] worker_thread+0x118/0x510
[ 1180.647313]  [<ffffffff8108e1f0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x3d0/0x3d0
[ 1180.647317]  [<ffffffff81093802>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
[ 1180.647321]  [<ffffffff81093730>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
[ 1180.647326]  [<ffffffff817b6698>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
[ 1180.647330]  [<ffffffff81093730>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
```

Comment: Could be an interrupt to a non-responsive device, though I guess Linux has some mechanism to not hang forever on those. Include the output of `dmesg` in your post.

Comment: @Alex: Ok, looked through the dmesg and added the part that I think may be relevant. There was a nss-myhostname warning but I don't think it is related. Let me know if you need anything more - can't paste the whole output due to post limitations