# Cannot get Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 to work in ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: wireless, 15.04, intel-wireless, centrino

I have Ubuntu 15.04 but I am unable to get my Wireless (Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000) to work. Any help. I'm new to Linux.

Comment: please post the outputs of the following commands, so that we can help. `sudo ifconfig -a` and `sudo lspci -vv`.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the link for commands you asked to run.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14352903/

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems your wifi card is seen by your system fine. You just need to configure it using either the graphical tools available with the desktop system (gnome by default) or through command line by configuring wpa_supplicant. Here's a link 
[configure wifi from command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiH_NaqtonKAhUJAxoKHdrgBL4QFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNGfnUA36OvdzjVGFhjDlCjZeeY12g)

Also check this [using network manager from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line)

Comment: Thanks I have also downloaded the drivers from intellinux site for my model but I don't know how to install them. I actually want to create wifi hotspot so each time system starts,, hotspot automatically starts.

Comment: You don't need drivers, the system already sees the card fine. You just need to configure the card. If you want to make it a hot-spot then you need a software package called "hostapd". Check these sites for detailed help. https://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-setting-wireless-access-point/

Comment: Ok but I'm unqble to understand the instructions on the link u sent which one i have to follow to create hotspot and connect to wifi

Comment: First one. Just follow the steps. Are you familiar with Linux command line tools ?

Comment: No not at all I'm new to linux

Comment: Ok then, i suggest you ask a friend or neighbour to help. Sorry i can't help further