# Troubleshoot personal internet failure

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, dns

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and we have Wifi in the house. Lately (every 2 days), my laptop fails to connect. The Wifi sign loads forever (you know the white lines going bottom-up recursively).

The issue is resolved with restarting the rooter. However, this causes problems to the other people that are successfully connected to internet (father and brother) via Windows OSes and the telephone which needs a non-negligible time to recover.

So, I was wondering if there is something I could do in person to try to recover, maybe resetting something, like my DNS configuration or something? I have no idea, do you? :)

Comment: Try `sudo service NetworkManager restart`.

Comment: That should be an answer, I think, @Jos. Now Internet is fine, so I will write that in a .txt for the hard times.

Comment: I believe @Jos means: `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: @chili555 on my 16.04 (systemd) system, both `systemctl restart NetworkManager` and `systemctl restart network-manager` work. And they start up the same service `NetworkManager.service`. Apparently, someone has had the good idea to create an alias.

Comment: Try to connect/evaluate the connection with the command-line utility **nmcli**
This will give you more output about what is really happening.

Comment: This prompts me to help, if I just run `nmcli`.

Comment: try  **nmcli g** **nmcli r** and **nmcli c** 

See here for more info: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try in case of a failing network connection that does not lie outside the system is to restart the Network Manager service.

On pre-systemd machines (like 14.04) the command is `sudo service NetworkManager restart`.

On systemd machines you would do either `systemctl restart NetworkManager` or `systemctl restart network-manager`.