# Wired ethernet not detected 16.04 using ifconfig

Tags: dell, ethernet, ifconfig

I just installed ubuntu and don't have my wireless or wired connections working yet.

When I type in the following:

> ifconfig

I don't see anything like "eth#" but instead "enp0s31f6": 
[enp0s31f6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEulb.jpg)

If I want to manually add the ethernet address under IPv4 Settings but do not know the address, net mask and gateway from the ifconfig outputs, what should I do?

Comment: The interface name is OK. You do not see the address because it is net set. If you set it, you will see it ))).

Comment: You should reboot your PC after installation. The WiFi and Ethernet connections should work "out of the box". If you have access to internet, upgrade the system. This happened to me time ago in a SBPC, I just connected to WiFi using the listed interface, and upgraded. The interface was named like 8X46567435..... So, I used it with nmcli. Look here [Connect to wifi from terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line)

Comment: @Pilot6 How do I set the address, when I do not know the address, net mask and gateway values? my /etc/network/interfaces file only lists > auto lo; face lo net loopback

Comment: If you have the Ubuntu PC conected to a router with an active DHCP Server then try **sudo dhclient enp0s31f6**