# Connect WPA2 WiFi automatically in command line Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, wireless

I’m operating a command line only install of Ubuntu 14.04, and WiFi won’t work. I can’t get it to automatically work either. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You need to lay out in more detail, what you have tried so far.
Maybe those answers can help you with your problem: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line/138476#138476),  [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line/461831#461831)