# How do I run GNOME Wi-Fi selection dialog through terminal with command line?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-shell

I need to run this Wi-Fi selection dialog through Terminal with command line. It is possible?

[image: wifi selection dialog]

It is similar to `gnome-control-center wifi` but I need exactly this dialog. Or maybe there is alternative Linux clients for Wi-Fi connection? There should be no preferences just dialog for connect to Wi-Fi hotspot

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Why not use the normal command line wifi?    See https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line  (how to connect to wifi from the command line)

Comment: Because I need gui for connecting but I need it call from terminal. There is also gnome-control-center wifi panel there you can modify your wifi connections.

Answer (score 2):

Type `nmtui` then pick connection. Done

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
gnome-control-center wifi
```