# How to open the little wifi dialog from command line?

Tags: command-line, wireless, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

#### My goal

I want to set a **shortcut** to open the **Select Network dialog** that opens from the top left system menu. The graphic way to open it is to click on the top left corner, then on your network, then on "Select Network", like below.

[image: Graphic way]
[image: The dialog I want to open]

#### What I've tried

- I've seen [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059289/how-do-i-run-gnome-wi-fi-selection-dialog-through-terminal-with-command-line) that is kind of a duplicate but I want to set a **shortcut** and not just handle my wifi I command line. [How do I run GNOME Wi-Fi selection dialog through terminal with command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059289/how-do-i-run-gnome-wi-fi-selection-dialog-through-terminal-with-command-line)

  So I know I can run

  ```
  gnome-control-center wifi
  ```

  But this leads to the control center and not to the little Pop-up I want to access.
- I have also tried to write a script with `xdotool` but this is inconsistent as it needs some sleep because I pass through the <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> shortcut and then move in the top bar to reach the **Select Network** item.

  The script looks like that but I don't really think it's relevant.

  ```
  #! /bin/sh
  xdotool key super+F10
  sleep 0.6
  xdotool key Right
  xdotool key Right
  xdotool key Right
  xdotool key Right
  xdotool key Right
  sleep 0.3
  xdotool key Down
  xdotool key Down
  xdotool key Down
  xdotool key Return
  xdotool key Down
  xdotool key Return
  ```

#### Config

Memory: 7,7 GiB,
Processor: Intel® Core™ m3-7Y30 CPU @ 1.00GHz × 4,
Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 615 (KBL GT2),
Disk Capacity: 256,1 GB

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 64 bit.
GNOME version: 3.36.2

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking for text-based tools like [nmcli](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/1.26/nm-settings-nmcli.html) or [nmtui](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/nmtui.1.html), they generally ship with most distros and it's part of the NetworkManager package. They both have the hability to provide some sort of a shortcut after creating the connection.