# Ubuntu Server 16.04: connect to wifi network (usb wifi adapter)

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, wireless

### Situation:

I have a server with Ubuntu Server 16.04 operating system. I need to connect it to the wifi network using usb wifi adapter.

When I plug in usb wifi adapter and run `ifconfig -a` I can see this information:

```
wlx000e0008833e Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0e:00:08:83:3e  
                BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
                RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Wifi configuration:

- `network name (ssid):` developer-modem
- `password:` qwer
- `security:` WPA/WPA2
- `IPv4 address:` 192.168.0.109

### Questions:

How to configure wifi connection in Ubuntu Server 16.04 (from terminal)?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To configure the wireless networks from the terminal you can use (nmcli)**

`sudo nmcli --help`

`man nmcli`

**You can also use (nm)**

`sudo nm-connection-editor --help`

**Goodluck**

Comment: `nmcli` and `nm-connection-editor` actually worked for Ubuntu **Desktop** 16.04. But there is an issue using them on Ubuntu **Server** 16.4, cause these commands are not installed automatically. Is there any pre-installed command that works on Ubuntu **Server** 16.04?

Comment: i didn't use Server OS before always im using workstation, Check here for more details https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line