# Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Tags: apt

I've recently installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on my old laptop to use it as a home server, and I think I accidently skipped past the network/Wi-Fi setup. Now every time I try running any kind of commands at the end of each one it shows this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I can't even reinstall Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, please someone help!

Comment: Why can't you reinstall? You don't need Internet access to reinstall the OS, although it is helpful if you need 3rd party drivers and can reduce the amount of updates you need to install after system installation

Comment: How to connect to to WiFi from the command line: https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line . Ubuntu Server does not include NetworkManager, which is what you were probably expecting to use to configure wifi access. Either use the link to get wifi working, or plug in a cable.