# Gnome shell extenstions have to be turned back on after reboot

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Whenever I reboot my system (ubuntu 14.04 with gnome 3.12) all the gnome shell extensions turn off. I can just re-enable them and they work fine until I reboot again. What can I do to make gnome restart the same shell extensions on startup?

Answer (score 3):

GNOME 3.12 isn't available by default in Ubuntu repositories for 14.04. You must have installed GNOME 3.12 from the [Staging PPA of the GNOME Team](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging). They warn that:

> The packages here have been deemed not ready for general use, they have known bugs and/or regressions, sometimes of a critical nature. Mostly things should run smoothly but be prepared to use ppa-purge, when you encounter issues!

So you should report a bug about it as mentioned on their Launchpad page.

However, the workaround that you may try is as follows:

1. Enable all the extensions you wish to be enabled at boot.
2. Then, run the following command:

   ```
   $ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
   ```

   This would list all the extensions that are enabled currently. For example, the output for me is:

   ```
   ['apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']
   ```
3. Now, create a file called `enable_gnome_extensions.sh` inside `~/bin` folder with the following text in it:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "<output_of_earlier_command_listing_enabled_extensions>"
   ```

   For example, I would put the following line for my enabled extensions:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']"
   ```
4. Make this file executable with the following command:

   ```
   $ chmod +x ~/bin/enable_gnome_extensions.sh
   ```
5. Add this file to your Startup Applications for it to be executed at login. [Follow this answer for how to do it](https://askubuntu.com/a/243150/114818). The "command" would be the path to that file.

Reboot to test if it works.

Comment: I don't think it could work --- `/etc/rc.local` is run well before the user login and the graphic environment is up. I have the same problem with gnome 3.10, and I use exactly this solution but I have it in a script in my `~/bin` that I add to the startup scripts.

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for your input. I just tested it using `/etc/rc.local` and it didn't work. I have made necessary modifications now. Thanks once again :-)

Comment: In a fresh Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 updated to Gnome 3.12 today, I could not access startup applications in an easy way. This work-around worked: http://linuxandfriends.com/how-to-add-startup-programs-in-gnome-3/